# Wordpress get_sites custom order

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to re-order subsites of a wordpress Installation base on a specific ID order:

`array( 7, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1 )`

This is a generic code for `get_sites()` method (sites ordered by `last_updated`):

```
$sites = get_sites([
    'public'  => 1,
    'number'  => 10,
    'orderby' => 'last_updated',
    'order' => 'DESC'
]);
```

How to implement a custom order, based on a numeric array of blog_id?

Comment: This is not an answer but the array you passed to the `get_sites()` function has a duplicate key of `'orderby'`. This means the second one overwrites the first one, so in your array the `'orderby'` key will get `"id"` as a value, not `"last_updated"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your custom order numbers as a Custom Field meta value.
Then instead of [get_sites()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/), try using [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/):

```
$sites = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => 10, //accepts -1 for all
    'meta_key' => 'your_meta_key',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', //or 'meta_value_num'
    'order' => 'ASC',
]);
```